Cron Job / Schedule Command in Laravel
I am trying to make a command run at a specific time, using cronjobs with Laravel, the command I created is as follows:
$schedule->command('test:message')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->dailyAt('17:21');

Now, on the cronjobs tab in cpanel, when I set the job to run at the same time i.e
21  17  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/project_name/admin/artisan test:message >> /dev/null 2>&1

the command does not work, and when I make a change to work it once per minute i.e
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/project_name/admin/artisan test:message >> /dev/null 2>&1

then it runs the command every minute. All I need is the command to run only at 17:21 every day

The command is incorrect
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/project_name/admin/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

this is the correct command. You should run the schedules and laravel will handle the timezone and the correct time

I have in total 3 jobs to run, all at different time period, if I use schedule:run, won't it run all the commands together??

@milindprajapati It won't. Reading the manual should help

@milindprajapati no no it will run all commands at the appropriate times u set in the scheduler.
